# Как сделать сайт на локальном компьютере, доступным из интернета для одного порта

Tags: c#, windows, asp.net, windows-7

Есть компьютер с установленной Win7. Установил диспетчер служб IIS. Создал элементарный проект `"Hello World"` на ASP.NET. Все компилируется, сайт отображается по адресу `localhost/HelloSite`. Так же к компьютеру проброшен один порт статического IP. Тоесть если вбить этот адрес (Например ххх.ххх.ххх.ххх:45454) в браузер то запрос перенаправляется на этот же порт моего компьютера.

Собственно вопрос:
Как настроить IIS, чтобы при вбивании в адресную строку моего адреса: ххх.ххх.ххх.ххх:45454 диспетчер IIS возвращал страницу которая находится в виртуальном каталоге на localhost/HelloSite.

P.S. Для проверки работоспособности внешнего адреса написал на C# небольшую програмку с помощью `TcpListener` на "прослушку" этого порта и при подключении возвращаю статическую страницу. Все работает.

Comment: смотри про биндинги иис https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc731692(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Пробрось на порт 80

Comment: @banme К сожалению, я не могу пробросить этот порт, и 443 не могу.

Comment: @VadimPavlovich не порт, а на порт: x.x.x.x:45454 -> y.y.y.y:80. При этом весь IIS будет доступен по x.x.x.x:45454. x - внешний адрес, y - внутренний. Если нужен выборочный доступ, то возможно ответ в комментарии грунди.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам надо чтобы ваше приложение открывалось по адресу http://***:45454/ - вам надо создать новый сайт в IIS и настроить там привязку:

[image: Раз]
[image: Два]

Мастер настройки также спрашивает физический путь для сайта - это должна быть папка с вашим проектом.

PS
Возможно, хорошей идеей было бы сделать держать отдельные отладочный и рабочий сайты - первый на адресе `http://localhost/HelloSite`, а второй по адресу `http://localhost:45454/` с доступом извне.

Для этого можно воспользоваться возможность публикации из студии (не работал, подробностей не скажу) - или сборкой пакета из командной строки.

Для этого надо найти программу msbuild.exe - обычно она находится по пути `(windir)\Microsoft.NET\Framework\(версия фреймворка)` или `(windir)\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\(версия фреймворка)`, хотя 12я версия прячется где-то в Program Files.

Дальше набираете команду `(путь-к-msbuild) (ваш-проект).csproj /t:Package`. После выполнения этой команды в папке `obj\Package` окажется архив с сайтом и скрипт для развертывания, а в `obj\PackageTmp` - неупакованные файлы сайта, которые можно куда-нибудь просто скопировать.

Comment: Сделал так как вы написали, теперь  по адресу `http://localhost:45454/` сайт доступен, а извне по прежнему нет (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)

Comment: IP адрес у вас тоже "Все неназначенные"? Имя хоста оставили пустым?

Comment: Да. Только выбивает сообщение что эта привязка уже используется продуктом отличным от IIS. Если нажать да то можно перезаписать текущие настройки. Я нажимаю да. Какой продукт использует я не знаю и как найти тоже не знаю.

Comment: @VadimPavlovich а порт на брандмауэре открыт?..

Comment: Да проблема была в брандмауэре. Спасибо за подсказку. Не знаю как я мог забыть об этом.